# unable downloading images from FTP server

Tags: android, ftp

am having this problem and i think am missing something here. my project needs to access FTP server to download some specific image, but the code am using seems not working, note that am using the same code to download some text files and it's working just fine !!!!

here is my code :

*** Note : am using Apache commons ftpclient ..

```
try {
         File Imgfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "img.jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream buffIn = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(Imgfile)); // local location
         con.retrieveFile("/public_html/cam.jpg", buffIn);
         buffIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast customToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());

           customToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot Downlaod the image" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           customToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 150, 450);
           customToast.show();
    }
```

I also tried this :

```
InputStream Fstream = null;
    try {
          Fstream = con.retrieveFileStream("/public_html/out.jpg");  
          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Fstream);
                      FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(mFilePath);
                       bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                  stream.flush();
                   stream.close();

          buffIn.flush();
          buffIn.close(); 
         Fstream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast customToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());

           customToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cannot Downlaod the image" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           customToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 150, 450);
           customToast.show();
    }
```

I always get this try/catch message " Cannot Downlaod the image ",

please till me whats wrong, or point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[see this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html) complete example how to download and display image....

```
void downloadBitmapImage()
{
}
```